# How to apply javascript to a partial view which is called inside accordion?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, accordion

I have a cshtml which looks like this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();

    });

</script>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 id="report1">Report1</h3>
    <div>

        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Settings/SControl.cshtml")


    </div>
    <h3 id="report2">Report2</h3>
    <div>

        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Settings/SControl.cshtml")

    </div>
</div>
```

My SControl.cshtml looks like below:
I have included an external javascript file in this cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/App/pages/SControl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="left:0.01em;">
            <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:x-small;">Run Mode</span><div>
                <select id="Mode" onchange="SubmitMode(this)">
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">Run Continuosly</option>
                    <option value="2">Run on Schedule</option>
                </select>
                <br />

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:x-small;">Reccurence:</span><div>
                <select id="Recurrance" onchange="ChangeRecurrance(this)">
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">On Time Job</option>
                    <option value="2">Reccurring Job</option>
                </select>
                <br />

            </div>
        </td>
</table>
```

The similar tags are continued in the cshtml page. But the scripts are applied only to the first header of accordion. Though the same partial view is called in all accordion header and same javascript file is called in all these partial views, only the first header gets the scripts. How to address this issue. Please help me

The external js file is as follows:

```
$(function () {

    document.getElementById("Recurrance").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("starttime").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("endtime").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("divnoenddate").disabled = true;
    $('#noenddate').prop('disabled', true);
    document.getElementById("RecurEvery").disabled = true;

    $(".date-picker").datetimepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-100:+0",
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        controlType: 'select',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
        showTime: false,
        showMinute: false,
        showMillisec: false,
        showMicrosec: false,
        showTimezone: false
    });
});
function ChangeCheckBox() {
    if (document.getElementById("Mode").value != 1) {
        debugger;
        if (document.getElementById('noenddate').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("endtime").disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("endtime").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("endtime").value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you're purposely trying to include the same JavaScript file multiple times, you should only have the script tag for `SControl.js` in the parent view, not the partials.

Comment: Your creating 2 identical partials (both `SControl.cshtml`) which makes no sense, and which means you have duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) which in turn means your scripts would not work

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need to call the same partial view in accordion. How can I do it if not in this way ?

Comment: @TiesonT. I tried doing that but it dint help me. I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Anon_y_20_raj. What is the point of 2 identical forms (with invalid html) What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

I think `script` apply in page before load `Partial view`. You need apply `script` after load it. You can use `readyState` in JavaScript for apply after complete all html tags and scripts like this:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        // your code
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I created new project similar to your project and add `cshtmls and js`. Your external js apply to `SControl.cshtml`. For example, `Recurrance`div added `disabled` attribute (see below image). 
[image: partial view]

I think external js code is incorrect and has error like below image:

[image: Error]

Comment: i tried this but still not working. Only for the first accordion header it works. For the rest it does not work.

Comment: @Anon_y_20_raj So, I need see `external js code` to help you.

Comment: I have modified and added the external js file.

Comment: @Anon_y_20_raj I edited my answer. Please see this again.

Comment: Is there any problem with date picker ?

Comment: @Anon_y_20_raj What tool did you use for `datetimepicker`?